# Is using 2 GROUP_CONCAT safe?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, group-concat

I have a huge join, for store products.
I want to list my products showing

1. delivery_formats (webcast, audio, DVD)
2. price_ids (Unique record ids)
3. prices (the actual item cost/price)

To group this data together I decided to use 3 arrays by using 3 instances of GROUP_CONCAT like so:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Id SEPARATOR ',') as price_ids,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Price__c SEPARATOR ',') as prices,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Delivery_Format__c SEPARATOR ',') as delivery_formats
```

Here is the full query:

```
select field, field, field,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Id SEPARATOR ',') as price_ids,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Price__c SEPARATOR ',') as prices,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT price.Delivery_Format__c SEPARATOR ',') as delivery_formats
from db.ats_store_package__c package
left JOIN db.ats_store_package_meta_tag__c package_meta ON package_meta.ATS_Store_Package__c = package.Id
left JOIN db.ats_store_price__c price ON price.ATS_Store_Package__c = package.Id
left JOIN db.meta_tag__c meta ON meta.Id = package_meta.Meta_Tag__c
left JOIN db.ats_store_package_session__c store_package_session ON store_package_session.ATS_Store_Package__c = package.Id
left join db.ats_conference_session_presentation__c sp on sp.ATS_Conference_Session__c = store_package_session.ATS_Conference_Session__c
where package.Is_Active__c = 1 group by package.Package_Code__c order by package.Sort_Order__c
```

In php, I explode these 3 strings (prices, price_ids, delivery_formats) into 3 separate arrays.

Will my items in the 3 arrays remain/be in sync according to their price.Id?
Will my 3 arrays on the same row remain in sync? Personally, I am 99% sure,
but I'd like to hear from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your properties `Id`, `Price__c` and `Delivery_Format__c` have the same "distictiveness", meaning that they all exist disticintly to the exactly same count, then: Yes. If not: No. The indexes of your three arrays will most likely differ.

It would be a different story if you would remove the `DISTINCT` keywords, then I would have just said "Yes" in a way simpler manner. :)

Comment: even though I am creating 3 separate arrays, each field item is coming from the same database row, which is all I can hope for in getting what I need.

Comment: That is fine but not what I meant with distinctiveness. Not sure if that is the right word though. Image you have two rows in your database, all attributes are different but they both have Price__c the same value, lets say 23. So in that array you would only have one entry (due to the `DISTINCT`),   and therefore, follow up prices would be in the "wrong" index

Answer (score 0):

My final decision is to query the prices for each product separately.
It's not worth the potential nightmare when trying to do everything in 1 big query.